# How to change inputs values when change select option?

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I have a table like as below. Selectboxes and quantity inputs ids dynamically. But i know each table tr id's. I want, if select change, change all inputs values on the same line. Example: If select option value equal 1 and all input values like as 1 2 2 1 1 same line

```
| size/color | xs | s | m | l | xl |
|:-----------|:---|:--|:--|:--|:---|
|Blue <br><b>SELECTBOX 1</b>|input 1|input 2|input 3|input 4|input 5|
|Yellow <br><b>SELECTBOX 2</b>|input 6|input 7|input 8|input 9|input 10|
|Red <br><b>SELECTBOX 3</b>|input 11|input 12|input 13|input 14|input 15|
|Black <br><b>SELECTBOX 4</b>|input 16|input 17|input 18|input 19|input 20|
```

My code is

```
<table id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" class="wc-bulk-variations-table nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-pa_bedenpa_renk">Beden / Renk</th>
            <th class="col-xs">XS</th>
            <th class="col-s">S</th>
            <th class="col-m">M</th>
            <th class="col-l">L</th>
            <th class="col-xl">XL</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="product-row-mavi">
            <td>
                <span class="no-image">Mavi</span>
                <p>
                    <select class="form-control" id="product-row-mavi-lot">
                        <option>Lot Seçiniz</option>
                        <option val="1">Lot 1</option>
                        <option val="2">Lot 2</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="24" type="number" id="quantity_24" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                    <bdi>15,00&nbsp;
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span>
                    </bdi>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="27" type="number" id="quantity_27" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
                    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                        <bdi>15,00&nbsp;
                            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span>
                        </bdi>
                    </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="30" type="number" id="quantity_30" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                    <bdi>15,00&nbsp;
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span>
                    </bdi>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="33" type="number" id="quantity_33" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                    <bdi>15,00&nbsp;
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span>
                    </bdi>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="36" type="number" id="quantity_36" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
                    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                        <bdi>15,00&nbsp;
                            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span>
                        </bdi>
                    </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="product-row-sari">
            <td>
                <span class="no-image">Sarı</span>
                <p>
                    <select class="form-control" id="product-row-sari-lot">
                        <option>Lot Seçiniz</option>
                        <option val="1">Lot 1</option>
                        <option val="2">Lot 2</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="25" type="number" id="quantity_25" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                    <bdi>15,00&nbsp;
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span>
                    </bdi>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="28" type="number" id="quantity_28" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                    <bdi>15,00&nbsp;
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span>
                    </bdi>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="31" type="number" id="quantity_31" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                    <bdi>15,00&nbsp;
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span>
                    </bdi>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="34" type="number" id="quantity_34" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                    <bdi>15,00&nbsp;
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span>
                    </bdi>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="37" type="number" id="quantity_37" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                    <bdi>15,00&nbsp;
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span>
                    </bdi>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Change value to what?

Comment: input 1 = 1 input 2 = 1 input 3 = 2 input 4 = 2  input 5 = 1

Comment: Where do you see Blue, Yellow, Red?

Comment: demo is here: https://demo.ibocan.net/urun/yuvarlak-yaka-t-shirt/

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate the DOM using closest

I made a lookup table

```js
const lookup = {
  "mavi": [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
  ],
  "sari": [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 3, 2, 2, 3],
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
  ]
}

document.querySelector("table tbody").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.id.startsWith("product-row")) {
    const color = tgt.id.match(/row-(\w+)-lot/)[1]
    const row = tgt.closest("tr");
    const inputs = row.querySelectorAll("input[name=quantity]")
    const vals = lookup[color][tgt.selectedIndex]
    vals.forEach((val, i) => inputs[i].value = val)
  }
})
```

```html
<table id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" class="wc-bulk-variations-table nowrap" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-pa_bedenpa_renk">Beden / Renk</th>
      <th class="col-xs">XS</th>
      <th class="col-s">S</th>
      <th class="col-m">M</th>
      <th class="col-l">L</th>
      <th class="col-xl">XL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="product-row-mavi">
      <td> <span class="no-image">Mavi</span>
        <p>
          <select class="form-control" id="product-row-mavi-lot">
            <option>Lot Seçiniz</option>
            <option val="1">Lot 1</option>
            <option val="2">Lot 2</option>
          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td> <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="24" type="number" id="quantity_24" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"> <bdi>15,00&nbsp; <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span> </bdi>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td> <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="27" type="number" id="quantity_27" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"> <bdi>15,00&nbsp; <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span> </bdi>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td> <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="30" type="number" id="quantity_30" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"> <bdi>15,00&nbsp; <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span> </bdi>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td> <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="33" type="number" id="quantity_33" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"> <bdi>15,00&nbsp; <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span> </bdi>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td> <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="36" type="number" id="quantity_36" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"> <bdi>15,00&nbsp; <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span> </bdi>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="product-row-sari">
      <td> <span class="no-image">Sarı</span>
        <p>
          <select class="form-control" id="product-row-sari-lot">
            <option>Lot Seçiniz</option>
            <option val="1">Lot 1</option>
            <option val="2">Lot 2</option>
          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td> <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="25" type="number" id="quantity_25" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"> <bdi>15,00&nbsp; <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span> </bdi>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td> <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="28" type="number" id="quantity_28" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"> <bdi>15,00&nbsp; <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span> </bdi>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td> <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="31" type="number" id="quantity_31" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"> <bdi>15,00&nbsp; <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span> </bdi>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td> <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="34" type="number" id="quantity_34" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"> <bdi>15,00&nbsp; <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span> </bdi>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td> <input data-individual="0" data-table_id="wbv_f393cdad063d564d_1" data-price="15" data-product_id="37" type="number" id="quantity_37" class="wcbvp_quantity" step="1" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"> <bdi>15,00&nbsp; <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₺</span> </bdi>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This code gives me data-price but i want 5 inputs values change one by one 1,2,2,1,1

Comment: Now I know. It was not clear. Why do you want to change the quantity when someone changes the dropdown?
Anyway, see update

Comment: because this product only package can be selected. So if the user chooses "Lot 1", he can actually get 1xs, 2s, 2m, 1l, 1xl.

Comment: Ok NOW I understand. Please see changed script.

Comment: Thank you this code is working. But our id product-row-XXX dynamic. Can i get this automaticly and add code?

Comment: I did. Your lookup table needs to match what I can get from the selects that is changed.

Comment: This is dynamic: `const color = tgt.id.match(/row-(\w+)-lot/)[1]`

Comment: I saw, but this time i add all colors const lookup manually,
const lookup = {
  "XXX": [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
  ]
}

 is it possible?

Comment: I do not understand - I assume your backend knows the colours available and match them to the selects on the page

Comment: I'm not sure. If color name is change this code is will not working. But thank you so much for this